# Is the Trove library thread-safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, trove4j

Is the GNU trove library thread-safe? I am particularly interested in TObjectDoubleHashMap. I looked at their documentation, but it hasn't mentioned anything, so shall we assume it is not thread-safe?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its not thread safe. You can use synchronized or your own Lock to make it thread safe.

Answer (score 12):

It has utilities to make it thread safe. See:
http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/TCollections.html

Also, since the collections are mostly backed by primitive arrays, you can (usually) safely perform read operations (iteration/get) across multiple threads.

Comment: I realize now that Peter's answer was correct at the time it was given- I linked to newer APIs.